# How to display Uploaded file to the user who upload it in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a system where users can upload their CSV file in the Django backend. But I am facing a problem, I want to display CSV file only to the user who uploaded it. I make a field in the models which can trace the user who uploaded the file. Here are some of my codes.

CSV file model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=False)
    csv_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename
```

And the view logic:

```
def accounts(request):
    user = Data.objects.values('user')
    if user == request.user:
        main_data = Data.objects.all()
    else:
        main_data = "" 
    dict = {'main_data':main_data, 'name' : request.user.username}
    return render(request, 'accounts.html',dict)
```

I am only getting that else value ' main_data=" " '.

Comment: A `OneToOneField`? So, there's only one file allowed per user?

Comment: Yes, right now I focusing on one file per user.

Comment: `user = Data.objects.values('user')` is a queryset that returns dict values.You are checking if this is the `request.user`. You expression will never evaluate to `True`

Comment: @MarcellErasmus So, what is the right way to do that?

Comment: I'd argue that handling that limitation with its special cases is more complex then allowing many. But back to the topic: set a `related_name` and use that from `request.user`.

Comment: @KlausD. Can I use `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` also? What do you think that will be good too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare the `request.user` to a queryset and then also returning all `Data` objects. You need to use the `request.user` and then return only the objects linked to that user.

```
def accounts(request):
    main_data = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    dict = {'main_data': main_data}
    return render(request, 'accounts.html', dict)
```

Also you wont need the `'name' : request.user.username` in your `dict`. You can access the `username` through the `main_data`

Comment: your code almost worked but it is returning `<QuerySet []>` after passing `{{main_data.0.filename}}` in frontend

Comment: Are you sure the `request.user` has uploaded files? The queryset will be empty if no `Data` objects are linked to that user.

Answer (score 1):

Simply we can do:

```
try:
    data = request.user.data
except Data.DoesNotExist:
    data = ''
```

Also, check the example of one-to-one relationships in [Django's Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships).